# Storing values from list in matrix like form

Tags: python

I have the following list `L` for which I'm trying to store the values in "rows" logic locating each value
in the position given by dictionary `HeadersPositions`.

This is my current code, for which I tried `while element[0] != "V":` in order to change to a next row after get the last header that is `V` for each "row", but I got an infinite loop, then I changed to  `if element[0] != "V":` in order to control when to switch to next row but is only storing in list `row`,  the first position of header `B`

```
L = [
    ['B', 3], 
    ['T', 0], 
    ['N', 5], 
    ['V', 2], 
    ['N', 1], 
    ['V', 4],
    ['B', 7], 
    ['T', 2], 
    ['N', 9], 
    ['V', 1], 
    ['B', 1], 
    ['N', 8], 
    ['V', 3]
]

HeadersPositions = {'B': 0, 'T': 1, 'N': 2, 'V': 3}

rows = []
row=[None]*len(HeadersPositions)
for element in L:
    if element[0] != "V":
        row.insert(HeadersPositions[element[0]], element[1])
    rows.append(row)
```

My desired output is

```
Out = [
        [3,0,5,2], 
        [none,none,1,4], 
        [7,2,9,1], 
        [1,none,8,3],         
    ]
```

Seen like table would be like this:

```
B   T   N   V
3   0   5   2
        1   4
7   2   9   1  
1       8   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having renamed `L` to `data` (since `L` is a capital letter and `l` would also not be a recommended variable name):

```
data = [
    ['B', 3], 
    ['T', 0], 
    ['N', 5], 
    ['V', 2], 
    ['N', 1], 
    ['V', 4],
    ['B', 7], 
    ['T', 2], 
    ['N', 9], 
    ['V', 1], 
    ['B', 1], 
    ['N', 8], 
    ['V', 3]
]

headers_positions= {'B': 0, 'T': 1, 'N': 2, 'V': 3}
rows = []
while data:
    rows.append([
        data.pop(0)[1] if data and data[0][0] == h else None
        for h in headers_positions.keys()
    ])

print(rows)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 0, 5, 2], [None, None, 1, 4], [7, 2, 9, 1], [1, None, 8, 3]]
```

Note: this is ignoring the values of the `HeadersPositions`, and you should probably use a list there if that's OK.

Otherwise:

```
headers_positions = {'B': 0, 'T': 1, 'N': 2, 'V': 3}
headers = [k for k, v in sorted(headers_positions.items(), key=lambda h: h[1])]
rows = []
while data:
    rows.append([
        data.pop(0)[1] if data and data[0][0] == h else None
        for h in headers
    ])
```

Edit: You asked for some explanation of how it actually works.

On the outside:

```
while data:
    rows.append([
        ...
    ])
```

As long as `data` is not empty, the loop will continue to add new rows. Note that `data` itself is being emptied out. If you need `data` to remain unchanged, you could instead:

```
c_data = list(data)
while c_data:
    rows.append([
        ...
    ])
```

That would create a copy of `data`, and you'd use `c_data` inside the loop.

The lists that are being added as rows:

```
    [
        data.pop(0)[1] if data and data[0][0] == h else None
        for h in headers_positions.keys()
    ]
```

This:

- pops the first element from `data`, if there's still data left (`if data`) *and* the first element matches the current header (`data[0][0] == h`). `data.pop(0)` removes the first element from `data` and only the value `[1]` is then used to populate the list.
- if there's no data left, or the first value left in data doesn't match the header, it adds a `None` to the list instead
- and it does so for every header in the list of headers in order.

So, on the first row, it finds a value for B, T, N, and V in order, so they all get popped and added. On the second row, it doesn't find the value for B at the start, so it adds `None`, doesn't find T either so another `None` is added, but then it does find N at the start, so it pops 1 into the list, etc.

This way to construct a list for each row is called a 'list comprehension'. And `while data` and `if data` make use of the truthiness of a `list`, an empty list is `False`, while a non-empty list is `True`.

Comment: Ok, ok. It works pretty nice. but may you explain a little bit how it works the condition you have set and all what is happen within `rows.append([...])` please?

Comment: I've added an explanation, hope that helps

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and time to explain so good your solution. I think I understand the logic now almost 100%. Due to lack of knowledge/experience, I didn't have in radar `pop`, so was a surprise when I saw it in your code and how you use it to remove elements and make easy the population. And your 2nd approach to use list instead of dictionary it seems to be better and easier for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can try this primitive solution

```py
def function(L, keylist):
    final_out = []
    out = []
    for i in range(len(L)):
        k = len(out)
        key = L[i][0]
        value = L[i][1]

        while key != keylist[k]:
            out.append(None)
            k = k + 1

        out.append(value)
        if len(out) == len(keylist):
            final_out.append(out)
            out = []

    return final_out
```

results:

```py
keylist = ["B", "T", "N", "V"]
print(function(L, keylist))
```

```bash
[[3, 0, 5, 2], [None, None, 1, 4], [7, 2, 9, 1], [1, None, 8, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for share another solution. It is great and works wonderful and is useful to learn and to use to in my code only changing the `keylist`. I would but I cannot upvote since my low reputation. Thanks again